# How to write a Java code to copy a table in Excel ten times one below another

Tags: java, excel

Let's say that I have an Excel file which has a table and I need this table copied 10 times one below another in the same worksheet.
How do I develop this program in Java?

Comment: You can do something like that using [Apache POI Java API for spreadsheet software](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set from which cell range table will be started,below is code snippet

XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Architecture");

```
XSSFTable table = sheet.createTable();
//XSSFTable table = sheet.createTable(null); //since apache poi 4.0.0
CTTable cttable = table.getCTTable();

cttable.setDisplayName("Table1");
cttable.setId(1);
cttable.setName("Test");
**cttable.setRef("A1:C11");**
cttable.setTotalsRowShown(false);
```